# Does hadoop eclipse-plugin support argument

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop

I downloaded the hadoop eclipe plug-in from this website:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1262

Thus, I can run hadoop program inside eclipe, but I don't know how to use argument in this plugin.

For example
jar xxx.jar -agrument1

Is anyone know how to use argument inside eclipse with this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the hadoop eclipse plugin has a very limited feature-set. 
Command line arguments are not supported.